# c#: how to write JavaScript function inside c#

Tags: development, javascript, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, developer

How to add JavaScript function `window.print()`in C# code.

C# snippet :

```
private void CTRL3_5_Clicked(object sender, ClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        //JavaScript function here!
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

- Right Click on your solution
- Click Add Reference In the new popup window Type 'System.Web" in the search box.
- You will get the result System.Web.
- Click on CheckBox against it.
- Click Okay

[image]

Add reference to

> using System.Web.UI;

```
private void CTRL3_5_Clicked(object sender, ClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        //JavaScript function here!
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(),
                           "Print", "window.print();", true);
    }
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: ScriptManager does not exist in current context

Comment: add reference to using System.Web.UI;

Comment: I cant find it in references it is missing can i add it manually?

Comment: yes you can add it manually

Comment: but i cannot find it I am missing it i don not know how to add it?

Comment: Answer Updated with detailed steps

Comment: still getting the same error `The name 'ScriptManager' does not exist in the current context` please help me!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33311/discussion-between-gaurravs-and-nderon-hyseni).